# Integrating $\frac {1}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}}$ using a specified U-substitution?

Tags: integration

I'm doing a two part homework question based on finding the integral of $\frac {1}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}}$

The first part was pretty simple, just completing the square, and recognizing it as being arcsine.

The second part is a bit tougher, since it wants the integral to be found using u-substitution, specifically having $u = \sqrt{x}$.

I've tried doing some algebra to enable such substitution, but I can't really see a way to split up the radical and make it happen.

I'm starting to think the question can't be done, and is simply a typo or something in the worksheet, since I found another more obvious error a few problems earlier.

Am I simply missing something, or am I right in assuming the worksheet is wrong?

Comment: Doesn't really look like $\arcsin$, that would be for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}$.

Comment: The integral is $\sinh^{-1}(u/√6)+c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Archis, the integral is $sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{6}} \right) + C$.

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + 6x}} = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x + 3)^2 - 9}}
\end{align*}

Let $\quad$ $ u = x^{\frac{1}{2}}, \\ du = \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx \\  dx = 2x^{\frac{1}{2}}du \rightarrow 2udu. $

$\\$

This yields

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{2udu}{\sqrt{(u^2 + 3)^2 - 9}} = \int \frac{2udu}{\sqrt{u^4 + 6u^2}} = \int \frac{2du}{\sqrt{u^2 + 6}}.
\end{align*}

Recall that

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} = sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a} \right) + C.
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
\int \frac{2du}{\sqrt{u^2 + 6}} = 2sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{6}} \right) + C &&\text{where $u = \sqrt{x}$}
\end{align}

Comment: But what happens to the $2$? I think it's $2sinh^{-1}$?

Comment: Great catch, I forgot about the 2.

Answer (score 1):

The first method in the worksheet is
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2-3^2}}$$
Let $x+3=3\cosh u$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}} & =\int\frac{3\sinh u\,du}{3\sqrt{\cosh^2u-1}}=\int du=u+C_1 \\
& =\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+3}3\right)+C_1=\ln\left(\frac{x+3}3+\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+3}3\right)^2-1}\right)+C_1 \\
& =\ln\left(x+3+\sqrt{6x+x^2}\right)+C_2\end{align}$$
The second method reads
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}}=\int\frac{2u\,du}{\sqrt{6u^2+u^4}}=2\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{6+u^2}}$$
Let $u=\sqrt6\sinh v$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}} & =2\int\frac{\sqrt6\cosh v\,dv}{\sqrt{6+6\sinh^2v}}=2\int dv=2v+C_3\ \\
 & =2\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt6}\right)+C_3=2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt6}+\sqrt{\frac{x}6+1}\right)+C_3 \\
& =2\ln\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+6}\right)+C_4=\ln\left(x+3+\sqrt{6x+x^2}\right)+C_5\end{align}$$
A couple of answers popped up while I was typesetting, but hopefully this will be considered a reasonable answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an easier way to solve the problem than the suggested substitution.

Hint: Complete the square in the radical. $\frac {1}{\sqrt{6x+x^2}}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2-9}}$

Now, let $u=x+3$. Now, we have an integral of the form

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{u^2-9}}.$$

This integral easily yields to the trigonometric substitution $u=\sec t$

Comment: Yea, maybe I should have been more clear in my original post; that's actually what I did for the first part, where the prompt was to "Find the integral by rewriting the quadratic in the radicand in vertex form".  The second part however, which was the one I didn't understand, asked to "Find the integral by using the substitution $ u = \sqrt{x}$"

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\sqrt{x}, x=u^2, dx=2udu$ to get $\displaystyle2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{6+u^2}}du$.

Then let $u=\sqrt{6}\tan\theta, du=\sqrt{6}\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$ to get

$\displaystyle2\int\sec\theta d\theta=2\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C=2\ln\left(\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{x}\right)+C$